# WARNING: The DB_USER variable is not set

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker compose for my project. And I have a strange error after `docker-compose up --build`:

> WARNING: The DB_USER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.

How can I fix this error? (I was trying both ./.env and .env) What is wrong?

Project structure

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── project
   |---Dockerfile
|__.env
```

.env

```
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=post222
DB_NAME=edo_db
DB_PORT=5444

DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:post222@db:5432/edo_db"
DEBUG=1
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  django:
    build: ./project # path to Dockerfile
    command: sh -c "
      python manage.py makemigrations
      && python manage.py migrate  
      && gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 core_app.wsgi"
    volumes:
      - ./project:/project
      - ./project/static:/project/static
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    expose: 
      - 5432
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.8-alpine
    depends_on: 
      - django
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./project/static:/var/www/html/static
      - ./project/nginx-conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  
volumes:
    pg_data:
    static:
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I was trying both ./.env and .env"?

Comment: I mean I was trying these string in env_file: block of the compose file

Comment: which container is throwing this error?

Comment: Thank you for the question. Reason -- is typo in the .env file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the error was typo in .env
file: Replased

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:post222@db:5432/edo_db"
```

with

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:post222@db:5432/edo_db
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $DB_USER  #  see whether this variable is defined or not prior to below
```

to engage the variables in file .env you must source the .env file

```
source .env    # good

source ./.env  # also good ... same as above yet safer

. .env  #  also good since . is same command source

. ./.env  #  good too also sources file .env

.env  #  BAD - this just executes the file which happens in a subshell and has NO impact up on parent shell ( in the terminal you executed it from )
```

now after you have source the file confirm the variable is now defined

```
echo $DB_USER
```

now do your `docker-compose up`

Comment: BTW, note that `echo $variable` [isn't all that reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else). `declare -p variable` is generally preferable if the shell is known to be bash (as opposed to `/bin/sh`). If one needs POSIX compatibility, `printf '%s\n' "$variable"` is a better choice -- more consistent handling of backslashes and other corner cases across implementations than `echo "$variable"`, which is itself better than `echo $variable` for reasons given in the prior link.

Comment: compose reads .env files automatically, so this is at least a incomplete answer, assuming you refering to doing this inside the django container. Its its regarding django, there are better solutions to doing this, i.e. using os.environ oder some dotenv package.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody lands here. I had a similar problem where my environment variables for Postgres were not being read by the compose file.

My initial project structure was as follows:

```
.
├── api/
│   ├── a-django-app/
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── .env.dev
├── frontend/
│   └── <some React files>
└── docker-compose-yml
```

and the `docker-compose.yml` file was as follows:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
    api:
      --other attributes here--
      env_file:
        - ./api/.env.dev
      depends_on:
        - postgres

    postgres:
      ---other attributes here---
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
```

What solved this problem for me was making the following changes:

1. Renamed `.env.dev` to `.env`;
2. Moved the `.env` file to the project's root directory so that it's on the same level as the `docker-compose.yml` file;
3. Updated my `docker-compose.yml` file `env_file` attribute to `.env`;

My new project structure changed to this:

```
.
├── api/
│   ├── a-django-app/
│   └── Dockerfile
├── frontend/
│   └── <some React files>
├── .env
└── docker-compose-yml
```

and my `docker-compose.yml` file changed to this:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
    api:
      --other attributes here--
      env_file:
        - .env
      depends_on:
        - postgres

    postgres:
      ---other attributes here---
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
```

I hope this helps someone who is facing a similar problem.